# Android Studio: "shared" module directories of KMM project keep getting unmarked as sources root

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a new project in Android Studio using KMM wizard. I was following [handson tutorial](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Networking%20and%20Data%20Storage%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatfrom%20Mobile/01_Introduction) and I noticed that I don't have an option of creating a package inside of some directories. Specifically, inside of "shared" module only kotlin directory of androidMain folder is always marked as "sources root".

I manually marked kotlin directories in other folders (commonMain, iosMain) as "sources root". I also marked sqldelight directory inside of commonMain as "sources root".

But Android Studio keeps reverting that state back periodically. I don't know what is causing this issue. It also shows that kotlin directory of androidMain folder is set as "sources root" and also is not. Which is weird, directory can't be set and unset as "sources root" at the same time.

Is it a bug of Android Studio, KMM Plugin or some kind of setting in preferences?

**Android Studio version: 4.1.1**

**KMM plugin version: 0.1.3-release-54-Studio4.1**

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

**build.gradle.kts** for shared module:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}
group = "com.example.kmmapplication"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }

    // Block from https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/2044#issuecomment-721299517.
    val onPhone = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") ?: false
    if (onPhone) {
        iosArm64("ios")
    } else {
        iosX64("ios")
    }

    val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9-native-mt"
    val serializationVersion = "1.0.1"
    val ktorVersion = "1.4.2"
    val sqlDelightVersion: String by project

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$serializationVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.1")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

sqldelight {
    database("AppDatabase") {
        packageName = "com.example.kmmapplication.shared.cache"
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework =
        kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

**settings.gradle.kts**:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == "com.android" || requested.id.name == "kotlin-android-extensions") {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
            }
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "KMMApplication"


include(":androidApp")
include(":shared")
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

Comment: This is likely a Gradle config issue. Please post `settings.gradle`, the `build.gradle` for shared, and Gradle version (from `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`).

Comment: @KevinGalligan Thank you for your comment. I posted code from those 3 files

Comment: Same issue. Every gradle sync make it "unmarked as root" which is frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

These ios target definitions conflict:

```kotlin
    ios { //Target 1
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }

    // Block from https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/2044#issuecomment-721299517.
    val onPhone = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") ?: false
    if (onPhone) {
        iosArm64("ios") //Target 2
    } else {
        iosX64("ios") //Target 3
    }
```

You have `ios`, which is a combined target for arm and x64, then the individual targets `iosArm64` and iosX64`. I don't know if that's what's causing the IDE issue, but it's certainly confusing.

The 2nd two don't define frameworks as they were taken from a context that would use cocoapods. If you look at the sqldelight issue comment, it came from me, and ultimately came from KaMPKit: https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/master/shared/build.gradle.kts#L28.

To get the IDE working, I'd suggest removing the first `ios` target. However, again, the sample from the sqldelight issue assumes you have cocoapods configured. You'll either need to add cocoapods or update both the target config and `packForXcode`.

The targets would look something *like* the following.

```kotlin
val onPhone = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") ?: false
    if (onPhone) {
        iosArm64("ios") {
          binaries {
              framework {
                  baseName = "shared"
              }
          }
      }
    } else {
        iosX64("ios") {
          binaries {
             framework {
                 baseName = "shared"
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

As an alternative, I'd suggest just using KaMPKit as a base for your project until you're more familiar with the KMM plugin samples and config options. They don't quite work out of the box yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm beginner in KMM and also I don't have great Gradle skills. I agree that those 3 targets conflict. I don't know how to add cocoapods to my project yet. But I eventually will do that. I tried to delete 2nd and 3rd targets and try to work with IDE. I also downloaded ZIP of KaMPKit app and tried to compile it. In all cases, those errors with Project structure are still present. Also, IDE seems to drop some dependencies from time to time, i.e. serialization and I get a lot of Lint errors. Only "Invalidate cache & restart" helps.

Comment: Do you think it is a bug in Kotlin Multiplatform plugin or Android Studio?

Comment: On which piece is having bugs, no idea. You should be able to resolve KaMP Kit, so I'm not sure what's going on. That is tested with Android Studio 4.1 and Intellij 2020.2.3 (I believe).